# jQuery $.ajax not working with url params in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery, parameter-passing

When i do the following:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://www.domain.tld/feed',
  dataType: 'xml',
  success: function(data) {
    ...
  }
});
```

Everything´s fine in IE(8).

But when i change the url option to

```
http://www.domain.tld/?feed=myfeed
```

IE does nothing. I think the **?** is the problem, but how can i get this working in this lovely browser?

Comment: Have you tried adding "feed" using the `data` parameter? It could be that the GET method overwrites any existing GET params in the URL

Comment: Do you have an error function in your ajax call that shows the actual problem?  Use error: sytnax here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Yes: textStatus returns 'parsererror',
errorThrown returns 'TypeError: Object required'

Comment: At least there is a server response. Have you checked, what exactly is send to the server? What does the server response?

Comment: hi Arne, did you consider that `http://www.domain.tld/feed` and `http://www.domain.tld/?feed=myfeed` are 2 different URLs?

Comment: First URL in my previous comment points to a resource at `http://www.domain.tld/feed` while second points to a resource/service at `http://www.domain.tld/` with query parameter `feed=myfeed`

Comment: Ajaxe: I know the difference between the URLs, i´ve got to change them by turns in my script to build an array out of two feeds before output. This works in all major browsers except all IEs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.domain.tld/feed',
    dataType: 'xml',
    data: "feed=myfeed",
    success: function(data) {
        // success handler...
    }
});
```

When you do this for a url: `http://www.domain.tld/?feed=myfeed`

I believe you are saying request to the default page in the domain: `http://www.domain.tld/`

**[EDIT]**

[Ajax IE Caching Issue](http://ajaxian.com/archives/ajax-ie-caching-issue)

Comment: Only the first feed has the URL "/feed", the second is just an argument for the base URL, not for "/feed".

Comment: Then it might be a caching issue with IE and get request.

Answer (score 2):

And if you use the data object does that work?

[see here jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> data (Object, String)
>
> Data to be sent to the server. It is
>   converted to a query string, if not
>   already a string. It's appended to the
>   url for GET-requests. See processData
>   option to prevent this automatic
>   processing. Object must be Key/Value
>   pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery
>   serializes multiple values with same
>   key based on the value of the
>   traditional setting (described below).

in your case

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://www.domain.tld/',
  dataType: 'xml',
  data: "feed=myfeed",
  success: function(data) {
    ...
  }
});
```